# Keystore expire in 5 months later

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

My keystore expire in 5 months later. if the keystore expired, how I update my app in play store and other markets?
What Should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If key expire it seem impossible to update your app. So make new app same as your current app then sign it with new keystore, publish it. In old app make new update that force user to install your new app (Ex : When open app, show dialog that user need upgrade to continue using). That's only way i know.

Sorry for my English if you cant understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Json2View](https://github.com/Avocarrot/json2view) Library

you can update your UI without update on google play so you can notify your users in old app!

Comment: then delete the main apk and upload new one, no way except this.

Comment: yea, you must have signed key to make update, or you never can't.

Answer (score 1):

According to @stefan-ferst in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754357/extend-keystore-certificate-validity-time?answertab=active#tab-top).

> The certificate validity is part of the certificate's signature. So
>   there is no way to change it in an existing certificate. The only
>   thing you can do is issue/get a new certificate with a longer
>   validity.

I assume to should publish another app changing `applicationId`. I'd use this remain time to update the app creating a campaign suggesting to current users to download the new app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to update the application if you lost the keystore file. i will suggest create a new apk with new keystore and package name and upload.